# why aren't logging files closed after celery tasks

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, celery, supervisord

```
def fn(filename):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(filename)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s:%(msecs)d], [%(levelname)s], %(message)s, ')
    handler = logging.FileHandler(filename + ".log")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.error("that's an error")
```

Basically I'm just using the python logging library for logging. The code is working fine if I run it as a normal python function.

However if I use it in celery/supervisord:
    fn.delay("loggingFile")
The file is opened and never closed (by the user used in supervisord). Of course, after some time, I have hundreds of opened files which is very bad and causes other troubles. Why is this happening with celery tasks only and how to avoid it?

I know the files are never closed by monitoring the system using lsof to see which users are opening which files.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the daemon does not close the file handler. you will need to it manually using after you finish logging:

```
logger.removeHandler(handler)
```